# How do I ensure Knockout.js mapping plugin does not map null to a property

Tags: knockout.js, javascript

With Knockout.js mapping plugin, how can I check to see if a value is `null` and return something else? For example, let's say my JSON from the server is:

```
[{'Name': 'Apple Pie'}, {"Name": null}]
```

Knockout.js mapping plugin will set the last item to null. How can I check to see if it is null and if so, then return ko.observable('')?

Comment: in your json you have 2 "Name" is that an array ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [the update mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#customizing_object_updating_using_update); enforce a default if the value of `name` is `null`.

```
var data = {
  pies: [
    { name: 'Apple Pie' },
    { name: null }
  ]
};

var mapping = {
  'name': {
    update: function(options) {
      return options.data || '';
    }
  }
}
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);
var pies = viewModel.pies();

console.log(pies[0].name()); // => 'Apple pie'
console.log(pies[1].name()); // => ''
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I missed that when I originally read the link you gave.